# 406 (Not Acceptable) in rails 4 with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4 and angularjs. I am follow railscast(http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs) tutorial. The tutorial on rails 3. 
The problem is that I am getting an error when I am trying to query data from database. Here is the error "GET localhost:3000/entries 406 (Not Acceptable)". I thing my angular code is working perfectly and may be the problem is in my controller. Because when I am using "localhost:3000/entries" link, I am getting this error "ActionController::UnknownFormat in EntriesController#index".

Controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json

      def index
        respond_with Entry.all
      end
end
```

angular:

```
app = angular.module("Raffler", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Entry", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/entries/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
]
@RaffleCtrl = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->
  $scope.entries = Entry.query()
]
```

view:

```
<div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="addEntry()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
      {{entry.name}}
      <span ng-show="entry.winner" ng-class="{highlight: entry == lastWinner}" class="winner">WINNER</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button ng-click="drawWinner()">Draw Winner</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to your routes config

```
resources :entries, defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very helpful. Any idea why the respond_to: :json at the top of the controller doesn't accomplish the same thing here?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. I've not noticed it. Thank you.