# 406 Not Acceptable Error with Rails 4 and AngularJS 1.3.x $http.get

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest

I have looked at other examples on StackOverflow, and I still need help with this.

My issue below is with the `o.get` function to retrieve a single post by its id.

While debugging, I have found that I am actually hitting this function when I click the proper link.  However, it is throwing a `406 Not Acceptable` error when clicked.

I am not sure if the issue is on the angular side, or with my show action, which is also found below.

Here is the code for my service:

```
angular.module('hackerNews')
.factory('posts', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var o = {
            posts: []
        };

    o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, o.posts);
        });
    };

    o.create = function(post) {
        return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data) {
            o.posts.push(data);
        });
    };

    o.upvote = function(post) {
        return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json').success(function(data) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        });
    };

    o.get = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/posts/' + id).then(function(res) {
            return res.data;
        });
    };

    o.addComment = function(id, comment) {
        return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments.json', comment);
    };

    o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment) {
        return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/comments' + comment.id + '/upvote.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            comment.upvotes += 1;
        });
    };
    return o;
}])
```

The show action:

```
def show
    respond_with Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is what is in my controllers:

Here is what I have in my Application Controller, I have the following:

```
respond_to :json
```

Most Controller is as follows:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        respond_with Post.all
    end

    def create
        respond_with Post.create(post_params)
    end

    def show
        respond_with Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def upvote
        post = Post.find(params[:id])
        post.increment!(:upvotes)

        respond_with post
    end 

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:link, :title)
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant Angular 1.3.x, not 13.x

Comment: Are you responding with JSON? The 406 error means the server's response type is not in your request's accept type list.

Comment: Do you have `respond_to :json` in your controller?

Comment: I updated question with what is in my controllers.

Comment: @basia. Thread update.  Where would i put the respond_to :json code, at the bottom of.the post controlleer?

Comment: I think the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579808/406-not-acceptable-in-rails-4-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `respond_to` (with list of formats you're using) at the top of your controller to make `respond_with` work. You can read more about it here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Post.all
  end

end
```

Comment: I added respond_to :html, :xml, :json 
at the top of my controller.  Now I am getting a 500 error.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. A work-around that I tried was adding '.json' to the o.get function like so:

```
o.get = function(id) {
  return $http.get('/posts/' + id + '.json').then(function(res) {
    return res.data;
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would solve OP's issue?

Comment: I just thought the page might not be loading because the PostsController#show action was trying to process the request as HTML when the response in the controller should be JSON. It's probably not a real solution, though